# Web site scraper wont scrape one of my links

Tags: python, web-scraping

I can scrape one site easy but the other i get error ??? Im not sure if its because the website has some sort of block on or something

```
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
from urlparse import urljoin

user_input   = raw_input ("Search for Team = "); 


resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://idimsports.eu/football.html") ###working
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

base_url = "http://idimsports.eu"
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(''+user_input))
if len(links) == 0:
    print "No Streams Available"
else:
    for link in links: 
        print urljoin(base_url, link['href'])

resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://cricfree.tv/football-live-stream") ###not working
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(''+user_input))
if len(links) == 0:
    print "No Streams Available"
else:
    for link in links: 
        print urljoin(base_url, link['href'])
```

Comment: what error do you get, and what line is it thrown on?

Comment: You're probably getting `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` (I am)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the user-agent header of your request

```
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
req = urllib2.Request("http://cricfree.tv/football-live-stream", None, headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

also on your second loop you're reusing `base_url` you probably don't want to do that.